# Powershell: Add a timestamp when the data was collected

Tags: powershell

i have this code

```bsh
$result = get-childitem "e:\tms\valid_2" -recurse -file | select fullname,*time 
echo $result
```

[image: sample result]

i want to add another column which will be the timestamp the data was collected like this and print it out as a CSV.

```
FullName    CreationTime    LastAccessTime    LastWriteTime   DatacollectionTime
```

Is this possible?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a calculated property:

```
# Add the output of `Get-Date` to each object as a "DataCollectionTime" property 
$result = 
  Get-ChildItem "e:\tms\valid_2" -Recurse -File |
    Select-Object FullName,*Time,@{Name='DataCollectionTime';Expression={Get-Date}}

# Export to csv
$result |Export-Csv path\to\export.csv -NoTypeInformation

# Or if you just want a string
$result |ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This works! this is also my expected result! thank you!